# State is not updating until 2 clicks and cant add new state to url in react native

Tags: react-native, state, react-props

I am having a problem updating a state. I fetch a JSON result using an address set as 'newurl' and display contents in a FlatList. It all works good and I have a button that when clicked updates the 'newurl' state and reloads the data. The problem is it needs clicking twice to update the state? I have tried putting the setState in a different class but does not work Also I have can not make new 'newurl' to include the state of 'newuser'

The onclick to update the state and reload the data which updates after 2 clicks is :

```
onPress = () => {   
this.setState({
  newurl: 'https://www.newtesturl'
}),  
fetch(this.state.newurl) 
.then(response => response.json())
.then((response)=> {
this.setState({loading: false,list: response.data})
})
}
```

The problem with making the 'newurl' string when updating it, I cannot seem to add another data state into it. If I use the code below, the 'newurl' is pretty much as is it, without adding the 'newuser' state?

```
this.setState({
  loading: true,
  newurl: 'https://www.example.com/userid={this.state.newuser}'
});
```

Its really annoying because when I add that into a direct url like  below it works?

```
<Image source={{uri: `https://www.example.com/userid={this.state.newuser}`}}  />
```

This is how I am setting up my props in case it makes a differnce? :

```
type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { list: [], loading: false, newuser: '10101', newurl: '' };
  }
```

Sorry if I have not explained it that well but if you need anything clarifying please ask, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State Updates May Be Asynchronous. See [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) for more info.

Second issue is because you don't use template string there. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for more info.